# How to access route information from a parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am having an issue with accessing the param id from the parent component. I understand that props are passed from parent component to child component, so for example the Dashboard component has access to the id, but the sidebar component does not. With that being said is there any way to provide the sidebar with that id so it can route appropriately when a tab is selected.

Signin.js

```
      case 'server':
        props.history.push('/profile');
        break;
      case 'manager':
        if (user.linkedRestaurants.length > 1) {
          props.history.push('/main');
        } else if (user.linkedRestaurants.length === 1) {
          props.history.push(`/main/${user.linkedRestaurants[0]}`);
        } else {
          console.log('Nothing for now');
        }
        break;
      default:
        console.log('You do not have a role');
    }
```

The sign in code evaluates the user role and then routes the user accordingly. For example when they are a manager the url would look something like https://localhost:1111/main/waod1289yu123unb and that would push the user to the main component.

Main.js

```
  return (
    <Layout style={{ minHeight: '100vh' }}>
      <Sidebar /> <---- I want to be able to access the id param here 
      <Layout className='site-layout'>
        <Header className='site-layout-background' style={{ padding: 0 }} />
        <Content style={{ margin: '0 16px' }}>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/main/:id/dashboard' component={Dashboard} /> <-- I am able to access it here
            <Route exact path='/main/:id/staff' component={Staff} />
          </Switch>
        </Content>
      </Layout>
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

The main.js component has nested routes in it, because the content will just be showing to the right of the sidebar. So in theory whenever someone clicks on one of the links in the sidebar it will call that handle routing method below and it should push the user to the "new url" should be the same as the one above, just append "/dashboard" for example. So https://localhost:1111/main/waod1289yu123unb/dashboard

Sidebar.js

```
  const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = useState(false);

  const onCollapse = (collapsed) => {
    console.log(collapsed);
    setCollapsed(collapsed);
  };

  const handleRouting = (key) => {
    if (key === '1') {
      props.history.push('/main/locations');
    } else if (key === '2') {
      props.history.push(`/main/${????}/dashboard`);
    } else if (key === '3') {
      props.history.push(`/main/${????}/staff`);
    } 
  };
```

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: the title of the question is a bit off. to help others search for a related issue, pls consider rewriting the title, such as how to access route information from a parent component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Sidebar` component, you can access the id of `Dashboard` by using the [matchPath](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/matchPath.md) function from react-router-dom.

```js
import { matchPath, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

...
const location = useLocation();
const id = matchPath(props.location, { path: `/main/:id`});
...
const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = useState(false);

  const onCollapse = (collapsed) => {
    console.log(collapsed);
    setCollapsed(collapsed);
  };

  const handleRouting = (key) => {
    if (key === '1') {
      props.history.push('/main/locations');
    } else if (key === '2') {
      props.history.push(`/main/${id}/dashboard`);
    } else if (key === '3') {
      props.history.push(`/main/${id}/staff`);
    } 
  };
```

Comment: this line here: const id = matchPath(props.location, { path: `/main/:id`}); assigns an object

//  {
//    isExact: true
//    params: {
//        id: "2"
//    }
//    path: "/users/:id"
//    url: "/users/2"
//  }

 of the potential match to const id. the id is nested in the param property.

Comment: I'm a bit new and I'm not sure if this is the appropriate place to do this, but thank you for the help gdh! @user3366943 Thank you for you assistance and answer below as well! This worked, I went back and checked out the React-Router docs and I'm not sure how I missed this the first time around haha!

Answer (score 0):

what @gdh is correct, but [matchPath](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/matchPath.md) returns an object, to get to that id, it can be destructured like this:

```
const { params: { id } } = matchPath(props.location, { path: `/main/:id`});
```